# Why are there two different types of operator overloading for the same operation in Vector3D class?

Tags: c++, vector, overloading, operator-keyword

I was reviewing somebody's code and came up with two interesting operator overloading methods. It is not entirely clear to me why the coder had to code the second method.

**First:**

```
inline Vector3D operator-(const Vector3D &a, const Vector3D &b) {
        return Vector3D(a.getX() - b.getX(), a.getY() - b.getY(), a.getZ() - b.getZ());
    }
```

**Second:**

```
inline Vector3D operator-(const Vector3D &a) {
        return Vector3D(-a.getX(), -a.getY(), -a.getZ());
    }
```

I understand what the first one is doing here, but is the second method necessary at all? If yes, what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is a unary operator. It allows you to negate the vector, reflecting it across the origin into the opposite octant.

If we guess that the class has a reasonable constructor and copy constructor, then:

```
Vector3D v( 1,1,1 );
Vector3D negatedV = -v;
```

Comment: How do you use it to negate the vector?

Comment: Just added an example.

Comment: Why is it taking an argument &a when it is just supposed to negate the vector?

The statement:
Vector3D negatedV = -3v
does not work right?

Comment: Is the overloaded operator in class scope or outside? As declared, it should be outside.